# how to put server configuration in git on linux

Tags: configuration, git

I want to track random config files / directories from my server into git repository. I do not mean tracking the /etc, here are some examples:

```
/etc/named.conf
/etc/named/*
/var/named/*
/usr/local/apache/conf/*
/etc/php.ini
/etc/my.ini
/var/www/config.ini
```

and so on...

since git does not follow symlinks, I can mount with bind, e.g.

```
mount /etc/named /REPO/etc-named -obind
mount /var/named /REPO/var-named -obind
```

I don't like this approach because it will do mount for each directory, but at least this is safe and will works correctly.

for files, I can do hard links, but I do not like the idea very much, because I can "lost" the link easily if I do something like:

```
mv /etc/named.conf /etc/named.conf.old
cp xxxxx /etc/named.conf
```

any suggestions how this can be sorted out?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't create a "configs" repo (or similar) and add the specific files/directories you want to this repo ?

Comment: Careful: you will lose meta information (permissions) and not be able to track empty folders which are important sometimes. Don't reinvent the wheel, check out https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper (but unsure if it can track files outside of /etc).

Comment: @Martin what is the alternative? Several repo's or all files in /etc ...

Comment: A single repo or 1 at the top of each hierarchy /etc or /var. Adding all of /etc will add lots of redundant data. @faker makes some good points though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it this way.

Instead, use a config management system (Ansible, Saltstack, etc.). Keep **those** files in version control and use that the CM to deploy config changes to your servers.

Doing things this way is highly beneficial in many ways: you have a full, offline backup of your server configurations, you can easily apply this configuration to multiple servers or to test/dev servers, etc.

I know this likely isn't the answer you were hoping for, but by all accounts, it's the professional way to manage systems.

Comment: What? No Puppet?

Comment: @ewwhite Haha, nope. Puppet's on my blacklist. :) I haven't used it for several years so this may have changed, but I also feel that it is much easier to get up and running with Ansible, especially for simple projects and one-off systems like this.

Comment: my goal is not automation and scalability, but sometimes we do changes to important files and later forget who changed what and when.

Comment: @Nick Exactly - this is a prime use case for using version-controlled configuration manifests.